# as3 get percentage of audio played

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make an audio progress bar that shows the percentage of the audio that was played and that will smoothly move up the bar until the audio is done playing. It starts on the left side and at the end the bar will be on the right side, showing its complete.

The following code below works but it jumps like 5 or 10 numbers at a time. I was
hoping to have the numbers increase slowly and not have them jumping. Example
it goes from 3 to 7 to 10 to 15 etc. How can I get the number to start at 1 and move up each number until we reach 100, at which point it will be finished.

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var lastPosition:Number = 0;
mySound.load(new URLRequest("audio/1.mp3"));
myChannel = mySound.play();

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkAudio);

function checkAudio()
{
    var duration:Number = Math.round((mySound.bytesTotal / (mySound.bytesLoaded / mySound.length)) / 1000);

    var seconds:uint = Math.floor(myChannel.position / 1000) % 60;
    trace('position: ' + seconds);
    trace("duration: " + (duration));
    var percent = Math.floor(seconds/duration * 100);
    trace(percent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first get duration from the `Sound` object properties, not from `bytesLoaded/bytesTotal` because this is another percentage instead of being a constant as it should be. And then, you should employ milliseconds in that calculation instead of seconds, because if your sound will happen to be less than 100 seconds long, the `percent` value will sometimes jump by more than 1.

```
function checkAudio()
{
    var duration:Number = mySound.length; // milliseconds
    var currentTime:uint = Math.floor(myChannel.position / 1000);
    var seconds:uint=currentTime%60;
    var minutes:uint=Math.floor(currentTime/60);
    var percent = Math.floor(myChannel.position/duration * 100);
    trace(percent);
}
```